# Does the Distant Spell metamagic apply to the Sword Burst cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic, area-of-effect

If this has been asked, I could not find it. My Sorcerer has the *sword burst* cantrip, and I'm thinking of taking the 'Distant Spell' metamagic option. Will it change the range to 10 feet?

Similar to [Metamagic Distant Spell and AoE spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/metamagic-distant-spell-and-aoe-spells) but not quite answered, though Crawford's tweet seems to imply it would work.

Although the spell has a range of 5 feet, it seems like Distant Spell would increase the area of effect in this case. So RAW it works, but likely shouldn't?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes

The Distant Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option states:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double **the range** of the spell.

And [*sword burst*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sword-burst) (SCAG, p. 143) states:

> You create a momentary circle of spectral blades that sweep around you.
> Each creature **within range**, other than you, must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 1d6 force damage.

*Sword burst* has a range of 5 feet and the effect hinges on that distance. Increasing the spell's range therefore increases the AoE to 10 feet.

Comment: Sword burst was changed to have a range of self in the new errata, so it doesn’t work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, but expect table variation

The spell description does use the word "range" but comparing it to fireball, I think the range of *sword burst* should really have been written "Range self (5ft sphere)".

The rulebooks don't distinguish range and area of effect consistently. For example: *sword burst* and *thunderclap* state "Range 5ft" for effects centered on the caster, but *arms of hadar* says "Range self (10ft sphere)", and spirit guardians just has "Range Self" with the 15ft radius mentioned in the description text.

As a GM I wouldn't let distant spell metamagic increase the radius of a fireball, so I I'd rule the same for sword burst.

### Damage Potential and Cost

(Assuming 5ft grid rules) A normal *sword burst* has the potential to affect 8 targets standing around the caster. Extending its radius to 10 ft can affect 24 targets. It seems a very low cost if 1 sorcery point can triple the number of targets.