# How does the Distant Spell Metamagic interact with the Thunderclap spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic, area-of-effect

[The *Thunderclap* spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thunderclap) has a range of 5 feet and states (emphasis mine):

> You create a burst of thunderous sound that can be heard up to 100 feet away. **Each creature within range**, other than you, must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or take 1d6 thunder damage. [...]

The Distant Spell [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) states:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double the range of the spell. [...]

Does doubling the range of *Thunderclap* also increase its area of effect or do something else entirely?

Comment: Related: [Does the Distant Spell metamagic apply to the Sword Burst cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150377/52137) (identical pre-errata to that cantrip), [Does the Distant Spell Metamagic double the range of area of effect spells that have a range of self?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122372/52137)

Comment: @Someone_Evil Yeah, I think that errata to Sword Burst is telling, that the other similar cantrips like Thunderclap, Word of Radiance and other will likely be have errata posted to follow suit.

Answer (score 1):

#### Distant Spell increases the area of effect of *Thunderclap*

When Distant Spell increases a spell's range this also affects anything that is determined by the spell's range. Some examples would be *thunderclap's* area of effect, *beacon of hope's* area of effect, or even how far away the caster and target of *witch bolt* can be before the spell ends.

Because *thunderclap's* area of effect is determined by its range and Distant Spell increases its range, it also increases its area of effect.

Comment: Thunderclap is poorly written I was thinking about Thunderwave in my previous comment. However Range and Area are separate things and Distant Spell only affects Range not AoE... seems the discussion on DDB echoes that. I would indicate it is a 15' cube with you as the center but not affected, since it defies all other defined AoEs. Not like we have a Doughnut AoE...:)

Comment: Answer seems sensible but is stated as an assertion without outside support or argument.  Can you elaborate?  Also, "can be heard 100 feet away" - this is _not_ determined by the spell's range.  Would this be doubled as well?

Comment: @Kirt There is no outside support because this stems from a natural reading of the rules. I can see no reason to come to another conclusion when interpreting the rules as the range is increased and the spell affects things within that very same range. And yes, anything with *an explicit number* would not be increased. This applies to things like *counterspell* which we [already have a question about](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128511)