# Can the Distant Spell metamagic override the restrictions of the Identify spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic

The Distant Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) for the Sorcerer class has this description:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double the range of the spell.
>
> When you cast a spell that has a range of touch, you can spend 1 sorcery point to make the range of the spell 30 feet.

The [*identify*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Identify#content) spell has a range of touch, but it also has the following text in the spell description:

> You choose one object that you must touch throughout the casting of the spell.

Does the specific text of the spell description override the Distant Spell metamagic, or can you cast *identify* on an object without actually touching it by using Distant Spell?

Comment: Arguably related (Distant Spell not overriding *counterspell*): [Can you effectively apply the Distant Spell metamagic option to a Counterspell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128511)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes, the *Distant Spell* metamagic should work on *Identify*.

The clause of *Distant Spell* that refers to touch spells overrides the part of the *Identify* spell that refers to touching the object. Most touch-ranged spells refer to touching the target in their descriptions, so if the clause of the metamagic is to mean anything, it needs to override the relevant part of the description as well as the range section of the spell stats.

With the metamagic, you will probably just need to be gesturing in the direction of an object that remains within 30 feet of you for the whole of the casting time (one minute using a spell slot, or 11 minutes if casting as a ritual). The exact details are probably something your GM will need to rule on (e.g. do you need to continually be able to see the object or not?), if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

### It will increase the range but you still need to touch it

*Distant Magic* will give *Identify* a range of 30 feet. However, the requirement that you must touch the object throughout is unrelated to range so *Distant Magic* doesn’t remove it.

Note that *Identify* has a casting time of 1 minute so “throughout the casting” has a different meaning than a creature or object you touch used in spells with 1 action or 1 bonus action casting times.

Comment: Does this same logic apply to other touch-ranged spells that also use the word "touch" in their descriptions? Does it make any sense for say *Cure Wounds* to still only apply to "a creature you touch" if its range has been extended to 30 feet?

Answer (score -9):

Remember that spells with casting time longer than one minute are cast EVERY round for the whole duration.

So if you are going to spend use the metamagic on identify, a one minute spell will consume 10 sorcery points if you wish to maintain the "distance" effect throughout the casting.

And if you dont spend the sorcery point, lets say on the round 3, you lose the distant effect, are considered not touching the object and the spell fails.

Comment: Since your answer is predicated on the assertion that spells cast over time require metamagic points to be spent for every round.

Comment: Just a heads up, Riveter: as the commenter above alluded to, sorcery points are only expended one time, at the time of casting, and the metamagic affects the spell for its entire duration.