# Can you effectively apply the Sorcerer's Extended Spell Metamagic option to the Thaumaturgy spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic

The [*thaumaturgy*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thaumaturgy) spell states

> You manifest a minor wonder, a sign of supernatural power, within range. You create one of the following magical effects within range:
>
> - Your voice booms up to three times as loud as normal **for 1 minute.**
> - You cause flames to flicker, brighten, dim, or change color **for 1 minute.**
> - You cause harmless tremors in the ground **for 1 minute.**
> - You create an instantaneous sound that originates from a point of your choice within range, such as a rumble of thunder, the cry of a raven, or ominous whispers.
> - You instantaneously cause an unlocked door or window to fly open or slam shut.
> - You alter the appearance of your eyes **for 1 minute.**
>
> If you cast this spell multiple times, you can have up to three of its **1-minute effects** active at a time, and you can dismiss such an effect as an action.

The Sorcerer's Extended Spell Metamagic feature states:

> When you cast a spell that has a duration of 1 minute or longer, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double its duration, to a maximum duration of 24 hours.

Even though the duration of *thaumaturgy* is 1 minute, the descriptions describes the effects as only lasting for 1 minute instead of "for the spell's duration". Can you use the Extended Spell option on the *thaumaturgy* spell to meaningful effect?

---

There are other situations with similar interactions such as using the Distant Spell Metamagic Option on the *counterspell* spell, as discussed in the question: "[Can you effectively apply the Distant Spell metamagic option to a Counterspell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128511)" Where the reaction needing to be within 60 feet of you isn't overridden by the spell.

Comment: Can you further explain why the bolded 'for 1 minute' text does not constitute the spell's duration?

Comment: @Token The same reason you can't apply distant spell to *counterspell* "[Can you effectively apply the Distant Spell metamagic option to a Counterspell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128511)"

Comment: Also, I think the Banishment example doesn't fit. How would it be phrased otherwise? "If the spell ends before the spell's duration ends?"

Comment: @Rykara "If the target is banished for at least a minute" but that's rather unreasonable, you have a good point. I'll remove it from the question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Technically no, but if this becomes an issue at your table, something, somewhere, has gone horribly wrong.

Following the logic of the linked answer to the adjusted range of Counterspell, a literal reading would suggest you can't extend the duration of the Thaumaturgy's effect beyond one minute because the effect duration is not literally linked to the spell's duration.

That is, it does not say "for the spell's duration [you can create an effect]."

But this is a *very* strict literal interpretation of the rules. We're taking about augmenting a *cantrip* with limited class resources. As a DM, I'd just let the player trying this have it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Extended Spell can apply to Thaumaturgy.

As you quoted, Extended Spell applies only when a spell lasts for at least 1 minute:

> When you cast a spell that has a duration of 1 minute or longer, you
>   can spend 1 sorcery point to double its duration, to a maximum
>   duration of 24 hours.

Additionally, Thaumaturgy has a number of possible effects, of duration instantaneous or 1 minute.

The only information you excluded in fact explains why Extended Spell can apply.
Under the casting details of Thaumaturgy, the duration section reads:
**Duration: Up to 1 minute**

This tells us that the duration is based upon which effect(s) you choose to use.

This sort of language is also found in the spell Prestidigitation, which also features multiple effects with different durations.

In both cases, it seems fairly evident that each effect has its duration listed with it, to attempt at being clear that not all effects last the same amount of time. But due to the admittedly poor wording of the spell, intent of wording priority is not clear, thus these questions.

So as long as you apply one of the non-instantaneous effects, you can use Extended Spell.

Comment: -1: I think OP know the spell is _eligible_ to the Extended Spell Metamagic (they do cite its duration in the question). This doesn't answer the main point of the question : even if you double the duration of the spell, each non-instantaneous effect explicitly states "for 1 minute" and not "for the spell duration".

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the Duration of the spell is listed as "Up to 1 minute". Which means the official duration of the spell is dependent upon which of the effects chosen. This can be seen as well in the spell Prestidigitation, another spell which has both instantaneous and longer duration effects. The reason why each effect has a specified duration is to clarify which that not all effects have the same duration.

Comment: The [official spell duration is 1 minute](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thaumaturgy), not "up to 1 minute", therefore not depending on the effect.

Comment: My copy of the Player's Handbook lists Up to 1 minute, which is why it is listed as such in my answer. But, that doesnt matter, because being listed as 1 minute means Extended Spell can still apply, as explained in the answer.

Comment: Then using the Extended Spell will bring the *spell's* duration to 2 minutes. The *effects'* duration stating "1 minute" don't change though. Which is certainly the reason why the question was asked.